# Renaming file in same directory -Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array with name VERSION that I take from mydir directory and it has parameters(files) as below:

```
VERSION[0]="TEST01_0.TEST01_1"
VERSION[1]="TEST03_1"
VERSION[2]="TEST02_1.TEST02_2"
VERSION[3]="TEST04_2"
VERSION[4]="TEST02_3"
```

And I was trying to rename TEST01_0.TEST01_1 as TEST01_1 and TEST02_1.TEST02_2 as TEST02_2.But I am getting some error as below:

```
mv: cannot stat `TEST01_0.TEST01_1': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `TEST02_1.TEST02_2': No such file or directory
```

Can you please help me to fix it? Here is my code block:

```
#!/bin/sh
VERSION=(/mydir/TEST*)
for file in "${VERSION[@]}"
do
    if [[ `echo ${file} | grep -o '_' | wc -l` == 2 ]]; then
    mv "${file}" "${file%.*}";
    fi
done
```

Thanks

Comment: `#! /bin/sh`? How are you running the file?

Comment: I save it as test.sh and copy it to the lab then run the `bash test.sh`

Comment: @OscarSayin: Can you run the script after navigating to `mydir`?

Comment: You say `VERSION` has `TEST01_0.TEST01_1`, `TEST03_1`, etc., but `VERSION=(/mydir/TEST*)` will mean it has `/mydir/TEST01_0.TEST01_0`, `/mydir/TEST03_01`, etc. Even so, the files should exist. Is this actually what you're running? What does `bash -x test.sh` output?

Comment: These files are already in /mydir. I just want to rename the file name which has two '_' characters as their last part of the original names. I mean I want to see my array elemenst like:`VERSION[0]=".TEST01_1"
VERSION[1]="TEST03_1"
VERSION[2]="TEST02_2"
VERSION[3]="TEST04_2"
VERSION[4]="TEST02_3" `

Comment: files are exist in mydir/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for this would be to run from inside `mydir` with `bash` as below and not relying on any third party utilities like `cut` or `grep`

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in T*
do 
    # Getting the string only containing '_' and if the count matches, 2
    # doing the file rename

    dashes="${file//[^\_]/}"
    if (( "${#dashes}" == 2 ))
    then 
        mv -v "$file" "${file%.*}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @OscarSayin: Happy to be of help!

Comment: can I ask you more question? How can I rename file from Upgrade.TEST01_0.TEST01_1.sql  to  Upgrade.TEST01_1.sql. I want to remove TEST01_0 from file name. I have tried like  mv -v "${file}" "${file##upgradeDb.*.}" but it didnt work.

Comment: Is it always after first two dots from beginning, i.e. skippping `Upgrade` and `TEST01_0`

Comment: I want to remove from first dot to second dot. I dont want to remove all after first dot

Comment: @OscarSayin: It might need a proper regex, can you post it as a new question with your attempt, I will try and quickly answer it

Comment: I found it :) I used this regex like mv $file ${file/${file:36:9}/};  and it worked. Thanks again for helps

Comment: @OscarSayin: be careful when using it that way, it will break if some new characters are added after `.`